# You must call removeView() on the child's parent first Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

1. Below are my both activities which i am calling .
2. I know this is answered before but my case seems to be different.
3. Can somebody look into this?

   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.View;

   ```
    import com.example.mediapipeposetracking.databinding.ActivityDashboardBinding;

    public class DashboardActivity extends DrawerBaseActivity{
    ActivityDashboardBinding activityDashboardBinding;


        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    activityDashboardBinding = ActivityDashboardBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(activityDashboardBinding.getRoot());
        }

    }
   ```

   ---

   Second Activity
   import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
   import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
   import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
   import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

   ```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.FrameLayout;

    import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

    public class DrawerBaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

       DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

        @Override
        public void setContentView(View view) {
            drawerLayout=(DrawerLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_drawer_base,null);
            FrameLayout container=drawerLayout.findViewById(R.id.activityContainer);
            container.addView(view);

            super.setContentView(view);
            Toolbar toolbar =drawerLayout.findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            NavigationView navigationView=drawerLayout.findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,R.string.menu_drawer_open, R.string.menu_drawer_close);
            drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }

        protected void allocateActivityTitle(String titleString){
            if(getSupportActionBar()!=null){
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(titleString);
            }
        }
    }


    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:5235)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5064)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5004)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4976)
            at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:687)
            at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:175)
            at com.example.mediapipeposetracking.DrawerBaseActivity.setContentView(DrawerBaseActivity.java:27)
            at com.example.mediapipeposetracking.DashboardActivity.onCreate(DashboardActivity.java:17)
   ```

Comment: `super.setContentView(view);` – Looks like you meant for that to be `super.setContentView(drawerLayout);` instead.

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense. You have one `Activity` class that extends another `Activity` class and in `onCreate()` you call through to `super.onCreate()` and in each class' `onCreate()` you call `setContentView()`. You should only call `setContentView()` once in each `Activity`.

Comment: @DavidWasser Look closer. `DrawerBaseActivity` does not override `onCreate()`. It's overriding `setContentView()` to wrap the subclass's `View` in the `DrawerLayout` setup.

Comment: OK, my bad. It is after midnight. Looks like Mike M's comment is your problem.